# Posting jQuery Datatable in ASP.NET Core causes 400 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc

I've set up a [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) table in my front end with server-side processing as it's a large data set. I've set up the Ajax call as below to post back to an MVC controller in the same application.

**Ajax call:**

```
ajax: {
    url: '/test',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (d) {
        return JSON.stringify(d);
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]DataTablesRequest request)
    {
        // Content removed for brevity
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

For some reason I'm always getting a 400 error back and the controller action is never hit. I thought it might be something to do with the fact that I have also implemented .NET Identity so maybe it was an authorization issue but adding the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute didn't help and I also tried adding `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` to the Ajax call which made no difference.

The `DataTablesRequest` model looks like this by the way:

```
public class DataTablesRequest
{
    public int Draw { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public DataTablesOrder[] Order { get; set; }
    public DataTablesColumn[] Columns { get; set; }
    public DataTablesSearch Search { get; set; }
}

public class DataTablesOrder
{
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public string Dir { get; set; }
}

public class DataTablesColumn
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Searchable { get; set; }
    public bool Orderable { get; set; }
    public DataTablesSearch Search { get; set; }
}

public class DataTablesSearch
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Regex { get; set; }
}
```

...and here's an example of the JSON that's being sent in the body:

```
{  
   "draw":1,
   "columns":[  
      {  
         "data":"col1",
         "name":"",
         "searchable":true,
         "orderable":true,
         "search":{  
            "value":"",
            "regex":false
         }
      },
      {  
         "data":"col2",
         "name":"",
         "searchable":true,
         "orderable":true,
         "search":{  
            "value":"",
            "regex":false
         }
      },
      {  
         "data":"col3",
         "name":"",
         "searchable":true,
         "orderable":true,
         "search":{  
            "value":"",
            "regex":false
         }
      },
      {  
         "data":"col4",
         "name":"",
         "searchable":true,
         "orderable":true,
         "search":{  
            "value":"",
            "regex":false
         }
      }
   ],
   "order":[  
      {  
         "column":1,
         "dir":"desc"
      }
   ],
   "start":0,
   "length":25,
   "search":{  
      "value":"",
      "regex":false
   }
}
```

**Update:**

It seems like this is actually something to do with SSL. I just sent the request in Postman and checked the Postman console which shows the following:

[image]

Comment: Yes - https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Got it ! Wait answering!

Comment: API Controller?

Comment: I've tried both an API controller and a normal MVC controller. Neither worked. I've also tried adding the `[ApiController]` attribute which didn't help.

Comment: Check my updated answer! Your problem is related to route. Route is not getting properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your DataTable ajax post is not getting the route correctly. So to keep it simple, first remove `[Route("[controller]")]` from Controller and then write as follows:

```
'ajax': {
     'url': '@Url.Action("Post", "Test")',
     'method': 'POST',
     'contentType': 'application/json',
     'data': function (d) {
          return JSON.stringify(d);
     }
 }
```

I have posted this from working code.

If you need the whole thing then it as follows:

```
var dataTable = $("#yourDataTableId").DataTable({
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            "order": [[0, 'desc']],
            'ajax': {
                'url': '@Url.Action("Post", "Test")',
                'method': 'POST',
                'contentType': 'application/json',
                'data': function (d) {
                    return JSON.stringify(d);
                }
            },
            "lengthMenu": [[5, 10], [5, 10]],
            "lengthChange": true,
            "searching": true,
            "scrollX": true,
            fixedColumns: {
                leftColumns: 1,
                rightColumns: 1
            },
            'columns': [
                { data: "yourColumnName", name: "YourColumnName" }

                //Other columns

            ]
 });
```

Comment: My DataTables setup is in a JavaScript file, not in my view so I don't have access to Razor helper methods. Also, I just tested it and `@Url.Action("Post", "Test")` also outputs "/Test" which is what I've set the url to anyway.

Comment: Surely you are missing something! This is 100% workable code. Try to figure out the problem. wish you all the best!

Comment: One question, Can you provide remote access with team viewer so that I can say the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should *inherit* from **ApiController** instead of **Controller**

Example from [Get Started with ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api#adding-a-controller)

```
using ProductsApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ProductsApp.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[] 
        { 
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
            new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
        };

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not for MVC controller or API controller? This is related to the route and ajax.

Comment: I'm using .NET Core. I don't believe `ApiController` exists anymore - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2